# Very confused on jQuery validate issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using query validate to verify that a user has filled out all text fields before sending me an email. Here is my form HTML:

```html
<form class="email-form" action="php/email.php" method="POST" id="emailForm"> <br />
            <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Your Name" /> <br />
            <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Your Email" /> <br />
            <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Subject" /><br />
            <textarea rows="10" class="required" ></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary required" />
</form>
```

And my jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#emailForm').validate();
});
```

I then visit the [page](http://mattaltepeter.com/new/contact.php) and submit the form without inputing any text and only the first text box gets the error message attached to it. If the first text box is filled out, the form gets submitted without any issues. Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of your validator setup code?

Comment: Where is Validation configuration code of your JQuery Plugin?

Comment: The validation scripts are included through 'head.php.' the jquery code above is at the top of the contact page

Comment: There is only one problem with your code... missing `name` attributes.  The jQuery plugin depends on them to function properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each input **must** contain a `name` attribute or the jQuery Validate plugin will not function properly.

Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with using `class="required"` within each element.

Try this instead:

**HTML**:

```
<form class="email-form" action="php/email.php" method="POST" id="emailForm"> <br />
    <input type="text" name="yourname" class="required" placeholder="Your Name" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="youremail" class="required" placeholder="Your Email" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" class="required" placeholder="Subject" /><br />
    <textarea rows="10" name="description" class="required" ></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary required" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#emailForm').validate();
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xSwfD/**

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know a name was required to make it work. Just hadn't gotten around to adding the names yet.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `class=required`, see what happens? The form will validate on email now. The way to do this is to give a unique name in the html. I prefer this way as it gives more flexibility to further customize:

```html
<form class="email-form" action="php/email.php" method="POST" id="emailForm"> <br />
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" /><br />
    <textarea rows="10" class="required small" ></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {

    $('#emailForm').validate({
           rules: {
                   name: "required",
                   email: "required",
                   subject: "required",
           }
   });

});
```

Using this you can get all kinds of fancy using messages, and other fields. See this good [tutorial](http://www.camcloud.com/blog/jquery-form-validation-tutorial).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6Xrc/2/) I was playing around with.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `class="required"` within each element.  The code was broken simply because the `name` attributes were missing.